# Using OUTPUT Parameters within Dynamic SQL within Stored Procedures- Possible?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a SP that I have created to check for validations and return an OUTPUT Parameter of 0 (No Error) or 1 (Error). However, I have to run this SP within Dynamic SQL since it will be ran through a loop of different data.

Can I pull the OUTPUT from the SP through the EXEC sp_executesql @SQL?

I can not post the actual code, but I can give an example..

```
DECLARE
@SQL nVARCHAR(4000),
@SPName VARCHAR(200),
@Parm1 VARCHAR(100),
@Parm2 VARCHAR(100),
@Parm3 VARCHAR(100),
@ParmDefinition nVARCHAR(400),
@Error nVARCHAR(1)

SELECT
    @SPName = 'spExample1',
    @Parm1  = '000000',
    @Parm2  = '111111',
    @Parm3  = '@Err=@Error OUTPUT',

SET @SQL = 'EXEC ' + @SPName + ' ' + @Parm1 + ',' + @Parm2 + ',' + @Parm3 + '

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Err2 nVARCHAR(1) OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Err2=@Error OUTPUT
```

**The @SQL Variable ends up being:**

```
EXEC spExample1 000000, 111111, @Err=@Error OUTPUT
```

^^Which works perfectly by itself.

Basically I'm trying to get the OUTPUT through the above code, but when it's ran through Dynamically.

Is this possible or is there another way to do this?

The way things kind of play out in the end appear to be:

```
EXEC sp_executesql EXEC spExample1 000000, 111111, @Err=@Error OUTPUT, @Err2 nVARCHAR(1) OUTPUT, @Err2=@Error OUTPUT
```

After looking at that it looks ridiculous, however any help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: The concept looks sound. What happens when you run it?

Comment: The OUTPUT value of @Error is NULL, not a 0 or a 1. Yet those are the only 2 options available in the SP: spExample1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get sp\_executesql result into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works perfectly (For N.. output and input parameters) please try this ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Myproc
@parm varchar(10),

@parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
@parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @parm1OUT='parm 1' + @parm
SELECT @parm2OUT='parm 2' + @parm
GO
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @parmIN VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @parmRET1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @parmRET2 VARCHAR(30)
SET @parmIN=' returned'
SET @SQLString=N'EXEC Myproc @parm,
@parm1OUT OUTPUT, @parm2OUT OUTPUT'
SET @ParmDefinition=N'@parm varchar(10),
@parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
@parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@parm=@parmIN,
@parm1OUT=@parmRET1 OUTPUT,@parm2OUT=@parmRET2 OUTPUT

SELECT @parmRET1 AS "parameter 1", @parmRET2 AS "parameter 2"
go
drop procedure Myproc
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in depth, but I did note the following:

When calling stored procedures, you can't mix-and-match named and not-named parameters. So instead of

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Err2=@Error OUTPUT
```

use

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Error OUTPUT
```

but, since the output parameter defined for sp_executesql is @Err2, it needs to be

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Err2 OUTPUT
```

This should work.

Comment: I actually don't think this is possible since you're generating a stored procedure code to be ran through sp_ExecuteSQL so you can't get an OUTPUT of an OUTPUT.  Anyway, I found another work around but I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: If you still remember the anwer, could you please post it and mark it as an answer?