# How to know total record return stored procedure in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure called `usp_getTotalOrder` which looks like

```
Select * from Order where CompanyID = 1;
```

Now, I have a table which contains stored procedure names.

In my BLL I have a stored procedure name. I want to create function which contain one parameter `StoredProcedureName`  and returns the count of total rows which is like

```
Declare @str varchar(50) 
Set @str='GetOrders';  // Stored Procedure Name
Exec @str
```

But it does not return total row count that I want to get from the stored procedure with its name in the function.

Any IDEA???
Please help.....

Comment: I want to count record which is stored procedure return.
Syntax not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `@@ROWCOUNT`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

You might be able to use something like:

```
Declare @str varchar(50) 
Set @str='GetOrders';  // Stored Procedure Name
Exec @str
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: How do you do this with stored procedure parameters?

Comment: @Ally I'm not following what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to return the row count as an output parameter in a stored procedure?  If so, let's say your parameter is named `@rowCount`.  Then at the end of your stored proc you would do `SELECT @rowCount=@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Using your example I had the case where the `GetOrders` stored procedure required parameters to be passed with it. But because your setting this as a string I do not know how to do this.

Comment: @Ally, ah, I get what you're saying now.  Couple options: 1: `SET @str='GetOrders' EXEC @str @param1, @param2` 2: `DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(256) SET @str='EXEC GetOrders @param1' EXEC sp_executesql @str,N'@param1 INT',@param1'`  Hopefully that makes sense.  I tend to use `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC` in these cases.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count the number of rows in the result set from the sproc?
In that case you could do:

```
INSERT INTO #Orders
Exec @str

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #Orders
```

or you could use a Table variable instead of the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the count of rows by output parameter or return value from your SP. Of course you have to add that output parameter to your SP and set it with COUNT(*) inside the SP.

```
DECLARE @o_count INT

EXEC GetOrder @o_count = @count OUT
```

Comment: Note that you cannot consume output parameters until you've read all the rows in the rowsets returned by the proc - kind of making the rowcount as output parameter in addition to rows basically pointless.

Comment: You can count the rows in the SP's query.

Comment: And if you return a row set or sets and put the count in an output variable, you cannot get to the count output variable until AFTER consuming all the rows, making it often pointless.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971497.aspx#gazoutas_topic6  A workaround is to return the count in a first rowset and NOT as an output variable.

Comment: OK than look at this example:
`CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrder]
(
 @o_totalRowCount BIGINT = NULL OUTPUT
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders

SET @o_totalRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
RETURN`

Comment: You cannot get the output parameter (from ADO.NET) until you've read the entire rowset AND called .NextResult on the datareader.  I've just re-verified this.

Comment: You saw somewhere mentioned DataReader in this question?

Comment: I'm not trying to get into an argument here.  That's just one way of consuming the stored procedure output.  The point is that there is NO way to get the count first in an output parameter and then the rowsets.  Same thing in pure T-SQL - the rowset(s) will be spooled, then the variables will be set.  T-SQL has no way to consume multiple rowsets or assign a SP output set to a cursor, so it's more limited anyway.