# Catch the sp_executesql table Result

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sp-executesql

I Have Stored Procedure by using sp_executesql:

```
USE [databasedevelopment]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SearchPaymentDev]    Script Date: 06/03/2013 16:42:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SearchPaymentDev]

    @PayAccountin as varchar(10),
    @PayCustNamein as varchar(30),
    @PayAmountin as int,
    @PayAmountPaidin as int,
    @PayResponsein as char (2),
    @PayRefNoin as varchar (120),
    @PayScreenTextin as varchar (100),
    @PayReceiptTextin as varchar (350),
    @PayDatetimein as varchar(50),
    @PayBankCodein as varchar (6)

AS
    Set NoCount ON

    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000) 

    Set @SQLQuery = 'Select * From payment where PayId is not null  ' 

    If @PayAccountin Is Not Null 
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAccount LIKE ''%'' + @PayAccountin + ''%'')'

    If @PayCustNamein Is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayCustName LIKE ''%'' + @PayCustNamein + ''%'')' 

    If @PayAmountin Is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAmount LIKE ''%'' + @PayAmountin + ''%'')'

    If @PayAmountPaidin Is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayAmountPaid LIKE ''%'' + @PayAmountPaidin + ''%'')'

    If @PayResponsein is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayResponse LIKE ''%'' + @PayResponsein + ''%'')'

    If @PayRefNoin is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayRefNo LIKE ''%'' + @PayRefNoin + ''%'')'

    If @PayBankCodein is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (PayBankCode LIKE ''%'' + @PayAccountin + ''%'')'

    If @PayDatetimein is Not Null
        Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (cast(PayDatetime as date) = ( select convert(date , @PayDatetimein , 103)))'

    Set @ParamDefinition =  
                    '@PayAccountin as varchar(10),
                    @PayCustNamein as varchar(30),
                    @PayAmountin as int,
                    @PayAmountPaidin as int,
                    @PayResponsein as char (2),
                    @PayRefNoin as varchar (120),           
                    @PayBankCodein as varchar (6),
                    @PayDatetimein as varchar(50)'


    Execute sp_Executesql     
                @SQLQuery, 
                @ParamDefinition, 
                @PayAccountin, 
                @PayCustNamein, 
                @PayAmountin, 
                @PayAmountPaidin,
                @PayResponsein,
                @PayRefNoin,
                @PayBankCodein,
                @PayDatetimein



    If @@ERROR <> 0 GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set NoCount OFF
    Return(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)
```

Right now i use the stored procedure on vb.net code behind and get the data as datatable and process on VB.net Code behind.

but now I Want to get the table result query and progress to the same `stored procedure` to change some of the field value, is it possible to catch the table first on the stored procedure, change the value and give output to be used on vb.net ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable

Comment: @DavidBrabant yup, almost. i already try the output method but it give me only top 1 value, i want all row :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchPayment]

    @PayAccountin AS VARCHAR(10),
    @PayCustNamein AS VARCHAR(30),
    @PayAmountin AS INT,
    @PayAmountPaidin AS INT,
    @PayResponsein AS CHAR (2),
    @PayRefNoin AS VARCHAR (120),
    @PayScreenTextin AS VARCHAR (100),
    @PayReceiptTextin AS VARCHAR (350),
    @PayDatetimein AS VARCHAR(50),
    @PayBankCodein AS VARCHAR (6)

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @OwnTran BIT

    SET @OwnTran = 0

    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 
        BEGIN 
            SET @OwnTran = 1
            BEGIN TRAN
        END

    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(4000)

        SELECT @SQLQuery = '

        IF OBJECT_ID (N''tempdb.dbo.##test'') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##test

        SELECT * 
        INTO ##test
        FROM payment 
        WHERE PayId is not null  ' 
                + ISNULL(' And (PayAccount LIKE ''%''' + @PayAccountin + '''%'')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (PayCustName LIKE ''%''' + @PayCustNamein + '''%'')', '') 
                + ISNULL(' And (PayAmount LIKE =' + CAST(@PayAmountin AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (PayAmountPaid =' + CAST(@PayAmountPaidin AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (PayResponse LIKE ''%''' + @PayResponsein + '''%'')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (PayRefNo LIKE ''%''' + @PayRefNoin + '''%'')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (PayBankCode LIKE ''%''' + @PayAccountin + '''%'')', '')
                + ISNULL(' And (cast(PayDatetime as date) = convert(date, @PayDatetimein , 103))', '')

        EXEC sys.sp_Executesql @SQLQuery

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            ROLLBACK TRAN

    END CATCH

    IF @OwnTran = 1
        AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRAN
        END
END
```

Comment: After executing the query above just run the simple following select: `SELECT * FROM ##test`