# Getting output in a variable from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I am using a dynamic `sql` i.e.

```
DECLARE @searchstring VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @str = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ' + @searchstring
EXECUTE @str
```

What I need is I want to select one column value from above dynamic sql to pass in a different `SP`
 Let's say I need ID column value and pass it to another sp named GetAnotherData @Ids. How can I do that?

Comment: Chekc this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I got an idea that how to proceed.

Comment: Do you want to select a single row or all rows in the column. Could you clarify that, please?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko All Rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you can go with Alexander Fedorenko example, but if you don't want to create any temp tables, you can use output xml parameter to pass your ids:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max), @Data xml, @searchstring nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = '
    select @Data = (
        select id
        from Table1
        where ' + @searchstring + '
        for xml raw(''Data'')
    )
'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt,
    @params = N'@Data xml output',
    @Data = @Data output

select
    T.C.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @Data.nodes('Data') as T(C)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55800/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

The following example creates a user-defined table type that has one Id column. Further the `INSERT @RetIds EXEC(@STR)` statement fills the parameter list, and then passes the values to a stored procedure

```
CREATE TYPE RetIds AS TABLE
 (
  Id int
  )

DECLARE @searchstring varchar(500) = 'AND SearchCol = 1'
DECLARE @str varchar(max)
SELECT @str ='SELECT Id FROM dbo.test6 WHERE 1 = 1 ' + @searchstring

DECLARE @RetIds AS RetIds
INSERT @RetIds
EXEC(@str)
EXEC dbo.ExecIds @RetIds
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60cc5/1)

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to pass the data set to a stored procedure without creating a temp table. No magic bullet here;)...

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko there's a way with xml parameter :) don't know if OP'll like it

Comment: Ok. This means we can pass xml type to a stored procedure.
It's fun, a little bit awkward, but interesting;)catch +1 Roman

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko thanks, yes, it is a bit awkward that's why not all my collegaues use it :) but I personally like xml support in SQL Server, it often helps me