# Why do I get: Error converting data type varchar to float on my Stored Procudure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get the error `Error converting data type varchar to float.` I only use float one and its at `@total`. I need to use float to do mathematical calculations.

I've shown in comments where it highlight if I double click.

I'm not sure why I get the error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_TargetStatus]
(
    @Year INT,
    @Quarter NVARCHAR(max),
    @LeadAssessor NVARCHAR(max),
    @ORG_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Server As nvarchar(Max)
    Declare @serverMan As nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @Tsql1 AS nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @Tsql2 AS nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @MANOwner AS NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @MANDB AS NVARCHAR(200)


--Server details


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp1

        SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
    (
        AUD_ID BIGINT,
        RowCounter BIGINT,
        DistinctCounter BIGINT,
        NACounter BIGINT,
        Total BIGINT,
        [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] @Year,@Quarter

    DECLARE @Total AS FLOAT
    SET @Tsql1 = 'SELECT '+@Total+' = COUNT(*)
    FROM ( --If I double click it shows error here        
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))
            THEN ''Over Due''
            ELSE ''On Time'' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
            AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@LeadAssessor as nvarchar(max))+'''))
            AND AUD_Year = '+CAST(@Year as varchar)+'
            AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From ['+ @MANDB +'].['+ @MANOwner +'].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( '+ CAST(@ORG_ID AS VARCHAR) + '))
            AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues]('''+CAST(@Quarter as nvarchar(max))+''')))DER'


   SET @Tsql2 = 'SELECT ([Target Status] + '''' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + '' of '' ('+ CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(255))+') AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) /'+ CAST(@Total AS FLOAT)+' AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101))--AND t1.[Status] in (''Open'',''Closed'')
            THEN ''Over Due: ''
            ELSE ''On Time: '' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
            AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@LeadAssessor as nvarchar(max))+'''))
            AND t2.AUD_Year = '+CAST(@Year as varchar)+'
            AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From ['+ @MANDB +'].['+ @MANOwner +'].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( '+ CAST(@ORG_ID AS VARCHAR) + '))
            AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@Quarter as nvarchar(max))+''')))DER

    GROUP BY [Target Status]'
    EXEC sp_executesql
    @Tsql1

END 
GO
```

Ive tried stuff like `@Total` and `Cast(@Total)`.

Comment: You're trying to concatenate the `@Total` value to the `@Tsql1` variable. You have to convert to string first.

Comment: @gvee: how can I go about to fix this?, Bit of a newbie

Comment: `SET @Tsql1 = 'SELECT '+ Cast(@Total As varchar(11)) +' = COUNT(*) ...`

Comment: So its going to happen on all `@totals` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link, You cannot get the output of dynamic query by the way you used it. You have to use IN and OUT parameters

[How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_TargetStatus]
(
    @Year INT,
    @Quarter NVARCHAR(max),
    @LeadAssessor NVARCHAR(max),
    @ORG_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Server As nvarchar(Max)
    Declare @serverMan As nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @Tsql1 AS nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @Tsql2 AS nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @MANOwner AS NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @MANDB AS NVARCHAR(200)


--Server details


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp1

            SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
    (
            AUD_ID BIGINT,
            RowCounter BIGINT,
            DistinctCounter BIGINT,
            NACounter BIGINT,
            Total BIGINT,
            [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] @Year,@Quarter

    DECLARE @Total AS FLOAT
    SET @Tsql1 = 'SELECT @retvalOUT = COUNT(*)
    FROM ( --If I double click it shows error here        
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))
                    THEN ''Over Due''
                    ELSE ''On Time'' END AS [Target Status]
                    FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
                    ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
                    WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
                    AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@LeadAssessor as nvarchar(max))+'''))
                    AND AUD_Year = '+CAST(@Year as varchar)+'
                    AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From ['+ @MANDB +'].['+ @MANOwner +'].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( '+ CAST(@ORG_ID AS VARCHAR) + '))
                    AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues]('''+CAST(@Quarter as nvarchar(max))+''')))DER'

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';
    EXEC sp_executesql   @Tsql1, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@Total OUTPUT;

    SET @Tsql2 = 'SELECT ([Target Status] + '''' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS NVARCHAR(255))  + '' of '' ('+ CAST(@Total AS NVARCHAR(255))+') AS TargetStatus, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) /'+ CAST(@Total AS varchar(100))+' AS [Count]
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,ISNULL(t2.AUD_CloseDate,GETDATE())), 101)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101))--AND t1.[Status] in (''Open'',''Closed'')
                    THEN ''Over Due: ''
                    ELSE ''On Time: '' END AS [Target Status]
                    FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
                    ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
                    WHERE t2.AUD_Deleted = 0
                    AND t2.AUD_LeadAuditor IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@LeadAssessor as nvarchar(max))+'''))
                    AND t2.AUD_Year = '+CAST(@Year as varchar)+'
                    AND t2.AUD_ORGID IN (Select Org_ID From ['+ @MANDB +'].['+ @MANOwner +'].fx_Rights_ORGIDs( '+ CAST(@ORG_ID AS VARCHAR) + '))
                    AND AUD_Quarter IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[fx_SplitCommaSeperatedValues] ('''+CAST(@Quarter as nvarchar(max))+''')))DER

    GROUP BY [Target Status]'



END 
GO
```