# Trying to run update with a variable that is a select statement

Tags: sql, database, variables, sql-update

This is in SQL server 2012. I'm on Sever Management studio.
I have multiple servers that have multiple databases that I need to feed it a varying list of Database names to pull back a sum of a size field.  At the moment @sql2 updates the BR_ProductionSize to the actual select statement instead of the answer to that statement.

```
DECLARE @TempCaseArtifactID NVARCHAR(60)
DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @answer NVARCHAR(200)
set @TempCaseArtifactID = (select '[EDDS'+BR_CaseArtifactid+'].[EDDSDBO].[File]' from #BRFindSizes where UpdateCompleted = '2') 
set @sql2 = '(select SUM(size) FROM '+@TempCaseArtifactID + ' where TYPE = 3 and InRepository = 1)'

IF (select BR_sqlServerID from #BRFindSizes where UpdateCompleted = '2') = 1015083
Begin
 update #BRFindSizes
set BR_ProductionSize = @sql2
where UpdateCompleted = '2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) the dynamic statement that you have created, to use the value generated.

What you should do is

```
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(50) = EXEC '(select CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(size)) FROM ' 
                                  + @TempCaseArtifactID 
                                  + ' where TYPE = 3 and InRepository = 1)'
```

And then

```
IF (select BR_sqlServerID from #BRFindSizes where UpdateCompleted = '2') = 1015083
BEGIN
    UPDATE #BRFindSizes
    SET BR_ProductionSize = @sql2
    WHERE UpdateCompleted = '2'
END
```

The same thing goes for `@TempCaseArtifactID`.

Comment: Whenever I put = EXEC i get 'Incorrect syntax near keyword 'EXEC'.

Comment: @user3754526 Did you try `sp_executesql`, as suggested by Dan.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is untested and might have some syntax errors, but it represents the gist of what you want to do.

You have this (actually, I put in the SumOfSizes alias):

```
set @sql2 = '(select SUM(size) SumOfSizes
FROM '+@TempCaseArtifactID + ' 
where TYPE = 3 and InRepository = 1)'
```

Which is a string.  To the the value, you have to execute that query and put the result into a variable.  This is the general idea.

```
set @valueIWant = SumOfSizes from 
sp_executesql @SQLString @sql2
```

Then you use the @valueIWant variable in your update query.

For the correct syntax, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable).

Comment: It didnt like '= SumOfSizes'.  I've also read your link and concluded that my brain is too frazzled to bring that all together at the moment.  Thanks for the help.