# How to use conditional statement "if not exists" in dynamic sql query within stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like this.

```
declare @insertQuery nvarchar(max)

declare @ifQuery nvarchar(max)

SET @insertQuery='...'

SET @ifQuery='if not exists(select Id from '+@DbName+'.[dbo].[tbl_TestHere] where Id='+@id+')'

  BEGIN
    Exec sp_executesql @insertQuery
END
```

I need to execute dynamic query @insertQuery if "if not exists(...)" returns true..But i couldn't find right solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? (Forget about the syntax problem when answering that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine to queries together.

```
SET @FinalQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = @ifQuery + @insertQuery;
EXEC (@FinalQuery);
```

Of course, you need to check if combined query is valid. Surround **@insertQuery** with `BEGIN` and `END` if needed.

If above combination is not valid for you, please check   [How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable).