# How to Embed Variable Value in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to be able to query Active Directory from SQL Server - see 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/

The following runs fine:

```
DECLARE @eid nvarchar(5)
DECLARE @username nvarchar(5)

SET @eid='123'

SELECT @username=sAMAccountName FROM OpenQuery(ADSI,'SELECT sAMAccountName, employeeID FROM ''LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com'' WHERE objectClass = ''User'' AND employeeID=123')
PRINT  @username
```

How to replace the hardcoded 123 value with the actual value of the `@eid`, so that the modified code will run fine as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly you have to build the SQL string ahead of time to add a parameter value into it and then execute the OpenQuery using that string. You must execute all of it as you would a dynamic query `EXEC sp_executeSQL ...`

Here's what I came up with:

```
DECLARE @eid nvarchar(5), @username nvarchar(5), @Query nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @eid='123'
SELECT @Query = N'SELECT sAMAccountName FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, ''SELECT sAMAccountName, employeeID FROM ''''LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com'''' WHERE objectClass = ''''User'''' AND employeeID=' + @eid + ''')'
SELECT @Query

EXEC sp_executeSQL @Query, @username OUTPUT
PRINT  @username
```

I may not have the output quite right.  Another option you have is to insert the output of the `EXEC sp_executeSQL` into a temptable and select the username from that value. For more info you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable).

Another option (and probably the easiest of all) is to move the `WHERE` outside of the open query and filter after you get the results back like this:

```
DECLARE @eid nvarchar(5), @username nvarchar(5), @Query nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @eid='123'

SELECT @username = sAMAccountName--, employeeID
FROM OpenQuery(AD, 'SELECT sAMAccountName, employeeID FROM ''LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com'' WHERE objectClass = ''User''')
WHERE employeeID = @eid

PRINT @username
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is a way to work with output values (since you'll return only 1 value):

```
DECLARE @eid nvarchar(5), @username nvarchar(50), @Query nvarchar(MAX)
SET @Query = '(SELECT @username = sAMAccountName FROM OpenQuery(ADSI,''SELECT sAMAccountName, employeeID FROM ''LDAP://mydomain.com/DC=mydomain,DC=com'' WHERE objectClass = ''User'' AND employeeID=' + @eid +') AS tblADSI)'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query , N'@username nvarchar(50) out', @username out
SELECT @username As Outputs
```

This will assign the result of the OpenQuery execution, in the variable @username.

We tested for Store procedure in MSSQL 2012, but should work with MSSQL 2008+.

Microsoft Says that sp_executesql(Transact-SQL): Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Windows Azure SQL Database (Initial release through current release). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)