# Assigning values returned by function in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sql-function

I am trying to generate a dynamic SQL to assign variables with values from a function. I am trying to generate SQL something like

```
Select @StartDate=@EID_Dept 
from dbo.WorkHistory(@today,@EID )
```

The function returns a date (@EID_dept will be the name of the column returned by the function) which I need to assign to @StartDate. And @EID_Dept is generated by concatenating @EID and @dept.

If I manually write the SQL it would appear as

```
Select @StartDate = amaan_IT 
from dbo.WorkHistory('2016-10-10', amaan)
```

My code is below:

```
DECLARE @EID varchar(5), @StartDate VARCHAR(MAX), 
        @today DATETIME, @dept VARCHAR(10), @EID_dept varchar(20);

Select @today = SYSDATETIME()
Select @dept = dept from dbo.Dept(@EID)
Select @EID_Dept = CONCAT(@EID, @dept)

DECLARE @SQL Varchar(max);
SET @SQL = N'Select @StartDate = @EID_Dept 
             from dbo.PeriodHistory(@today, @EID)';

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @SQL,
  N'@StartDate VARCHAR(MAX) out,@EID_dept varchar(max),@today datetime,@EID Varchar',
  @StartDate out,
  @EID_Dept=@EID_Dept,
  @today=@today
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql at all? It is not doing anything for you except making this more difficult.

Comment: You cannot assign object names using variables, you would need to use `SET @SQL = CONCAT(N'SELECT @StartDate = ', @EID_Dept, ' FROM dbo.PeriodHistory(@Today, @EID);`). This seems far from ideal though, I am not convinced that you are doing this the best way.

Comment: The EID will be changing and I need to concatenate EID n Dept to get the data from the function. Just EID will be passed , using EID I need to find out Dept and then concatenate both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get sp\_executesql result into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I changed your query a little bit. Hope this will work fine:

```
DECLARE @EID nvarchar(5), 
        @StartDate nvarchar(MAX), 
        @today datetime = SYSDATETIME(), 
        @dept nvarchar(10), 
        @EID_dept nvarchar(20),
        @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @params nvarchar(max) = N'@StartDate nvarchar(MAX) out, @today datetime, @EID nvarchar(5)'

Select @dept = dept from dbo.Dept(@EID)
Select @EID_Dept = CONCAT(@EID, @dept)

SET @SQL = N'Select @StartDate = ' + QUOTENAME(@EID_dept) + ' from dbo.PeriodHistory(@today, @EID);';

EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL,
                    @params,
                    @StartDate = @StartDate out,
                    @today = @today,
                    @EID = @EID

SELECT @StartDate
```

I used `nvarchar(max)` for `@SQL` (you are using `varchar` but adding `N` when assign value to variable). `sp_executesql` awaits `nvarchar` in *statement* part

> Is a Unicode string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

All parameters I put in `@params` variable.

As I understood you need to get another columns based on `@EID_dept`, so I add QUOTENAME and used this variable in SQL statement building directly. You can not send column name as variable.