# Conversion failed when converting varchar into INT

Tags: sql-server

I know there are a lot of questions asked like this, but I have tried almost all of the solution, but still can't get that one piece of code to work :( Here's what I'm doing - I'm trying to find the number of rows in a table so that I can use that as a counter to loop and delete rows.

`@rc` is INT, 
`@tbname` is varchar (500)
and `@id` is also INT.

This is my query:

```
set @rc='select count(*) from dbo.[' + @tbname + '] where id = ' + @id
```

I have also tried these:

```
set @rc='select cast(count(*) as varchar) from dbo.[' + @tbname + '] where id = ' + @id
```

and

```
set @rc='select count(*) from dbo.[' + @tbname + '] where id = ' + cast(@id as varchar)
```

And a few more permutation of placing cast here and there as well. I also tried changing the declaration of `@rc` as `varchar`, still get the same error.

Comment: You expect that merely *assigning* a *string* to a variable should cause the string to be considered as a query and *executed*? That would make for a remarkably surprising language.

Comment: This is the method you need to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable Try it and post back any questions

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add - I print @rc in the next line.

Comment: if `@rc` is `INT` then why you assign it with a string?

Comment: when asking a question please post all the code. This includes the `print`, and the `declare`. Anyway - go check the link I posted

Comment: @IvanSivak - shouldn't the count(*) give me an INT?

Comment: @Balaji `@rc` is a string. The execution of this string produces a scalar result that will be `INT`. But the `rc` itself is a string/varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sp_executesql in this case,

```
    DECLARE @retval int   
    DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

   DECLARE @rc          INT
            ,@str       NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@tbname    NVARCHAR(500) = 'Table1'
            ,@id        int

    set @str='select @rcOut = count(*) from dbo.[' + @tbname + '] where id = ' + CAST(@id as NVARCHAR)


    EXEC sp_executesql @str, N'@rcOut int OUTPUT',@rcOut = @rc OUTPUT;

    SELECT @rc;
```

Comment: Thank you. There was another answer an hour ago, something similar to this, I was able to use that. Not sure why that was deleted.

Comment: This is the correct method in this scenario, u dont need to create temp. table.