# Using sp_executesql to store a Scalar Result into a Variable

Tags: sql-server

I have followed the first answer found at this link:
[How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

```
Declare @Num int;
Declare @DB_Name nvarchar(50);

Set @DB_Name = 'Database';
Declare @query nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @parm nvarchar(100);

Select @query = N'Select COUNT(Field) From ' + @DB_Name + '.dbo.Table';
Select @parm = N'@Num int OUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, @parm, @Num = @Num OUT;
Select @Num;
```

The output from the Exec statement provides me with the proper result in the Results Window, however, the last "Select @Num" statement returns NULL.

I need to use the value of the @Num Variable in the rest of my code.

Am I missing something?

Joseph

Comment: Try using a second variable for the output and then selecting that variable.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, but I have tried this, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dynamic SQL you forgot to assign the query result to your @num variable

```
Select @query = N'Select @Num = COUNT(Field) From ' + @DB_Name + '.dbo.Table';
```

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you very much Shurik.