# Put the result of a EXEC sp_executesql into a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to put into the variable `@REGIMECASAM`, the value that is in the `REGIMECASAM` field, of the `COMPLEMENT` table, of the bank `FIRMAS` (Firebird).

The linked server for the `FIRMAS` database is working perfectly, but the variable `@REGIMECASAM` remains empty after the `EXEC` runs.

Note that when I execute the select with the content of `@QUERYTOTAL` manually, no errors occur, and the `SELECT` result is correct, and it has the value 3 as the content of the `REGIMECASAM` field.

This is the code:

```
DECLARE @REGIMECASAM INT

DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar (1000), @TSQL nvarchar (1000), @LinkedServer nvarchar (1000) SET @LinkedServer = '[SIGNALS]'

SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT REGIMECASAM FROM OPENQUERY (' + @LinkedServer + ',' ''

SET @TSQL = 'SELECT REGIMECASAM FROM COMPLEMENT WHERE LINK =' + CAST (@ CODEID AS VARCHAR (6)) + '' ')'

SET @QUERYTOTAL = @ OPENQUERY + @ TSQL

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERYTOTAL, N '@ REGIMECASAM INT out', @REGIMECASAM OUT

SELECT @REGIMECASAM The Outputs
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you mention `REGIMEASAM` twice as output parameter when calling `EXEC` ? Also, why do you have a space between the parameter literal `@` and the variable name?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable?rq=1) from the **Related** links on the right side of the page help?

Comment: The problem was solved !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved !

I changed the line below:

SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT REGIMECASAM FROM OPENQUERY (' + @LinkedServer + ',' ''

for:

SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT @REGIMECASAM= REGIMECASAM FROM OPENQUERY (' + @LinkedServer + ',' ''