# result of sp_executesql in a variable

Tags: t-sql, sp-executesql

How can I get the output of the below query in a variable without temp table?

```
DECLARE @Q1 NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @Q2 NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @Q3 NVARCHAR(300)

SET @Q1 = 'SELECT ' +' ' + @formfieldpath 
SET @Q2 = 'FROM [TestDatabase].[details] WHERE id ' + '=''' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(10)) + '''';
SET @Q3 = @Q1 +' '+ @Q2 

PRINT @Q3

EXEC sp_executesql @Q3
```

Tried '[How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)' and not able to get the results.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming** that you get a singleton value from your dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @ID int, --Is set somewhere
        @YourVariable nvarchar(30), --Use an appropriate data type
        @formfieldpath sysname; --Is set somewhere

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

--I assume that the name [TestDatabase].[details] is wrong, as [TestDatabase] would be the name of the schema, not the database,
--and I ASSUME you haven't foolishy created a schema called "TestDatabase"
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @YourVariable = ' + QUOTENAME(@formfieldpath) + N' FROM dbo.Details WHERE id = @id'; 

--Use the correct datatype for @YourVariable
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@id int, @YourVariable nvarchar(30) OUTPUT', @id, @YourVariable OUTPUT;
```

**Never** inject unsanitised values into a dynamic SQL statement. SQL injection is a huge problem that should have stopped existing over a decade ago. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working as expected. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: You're welcome @Andrew . Please do consider marking the answer as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful. You should also do so with your other questions; it's a very important part of the site.