# Store the value of a query into a SQL Server variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, dynamic-sql

The objective of the code is to run a query dynamically and return 0 if there are no rows with data present in the columns and to return 1 if there are rows with data in the columns. This is my code for the stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_ColumnFieldValidator] 
(
    @TblName nvarchar(30),
    @ColumnName nvarchar(30),
    @RetVal bit output
)


as 
begin

    declare @CountOfRowsQuery as nvarchar(300)
    set @CountOfRowsQuery = 'select count('+quotename(@ColumnName)+') from '+quotename(@TblName)+' having count(' +quotename(@ColumnName)+') = nullif(count('+quotename(@ColumnName)+'),0)'
    execute sp_executesql @CountOfRowsQuery 

    select @RetVal = dbo.fn_ColumnValidator(@CountOfRowsQuery)

end
```

As you can see, a user-defined function is being called to set the value of @RetVal. This is my code for the user-defined function.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ColumnValidator]
(
    @NullChecker as nvarchar(max)
)
returns bit

as
begin
    declare @returnVar as bit
    if @NullChecker is null
        set @returnVar = 0 
    else
        set @returnVar = 1
    return @returnVar
end
```

The output of @RetVal is always 1 and I have attributed this error to @CountOfRowsQuery storing the entire string rather than the value of the query ie: @CountOfRowsQuery = null if the count of rows is zero else, @CountOfRowsQuery = the number of rows present in the column. To make things clearer I am attaching screenshots of the output when I run the program.

1. [Output of a table that contains rows with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7E0y.png)
2. [Output of a table that contains no rows with no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaOio.png)

As you can see in list item.2, the sp returns null but the function_returned_value is being set to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: You execute the dynamic SQL, but don't bother getting the result. The `execute` needs work.

Comment: @HABO, I understand the code requires work, which is exactly why I am looking for an answer. Can you be more helpful by giving me more info about what exactly is wrong with the ```execute``` command or what exactly it is that Im missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get sp\_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The objective of the code is to run a query dynamically and return 0 if there are no rows with data present in the columns and to return 1 if there are rows with data in the columns.

Man, if this is not an over-complication I don't know what is.
Here's a much simpler (and more efficient) query that does the work:

```sql
SELECT CAST(IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName
    WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL
), 1, 0) As Bit)
```

Now, to change that to a procedure using dynamic SQL in a way that will not expose you to SQL Injection threats you can do this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ColumnFieldValidator] 
(
    @TblName sysname, 
    @ColumnName sysname,
    @RetVal bit output
)


AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Information_Schema.Columns
        WHERE Table_Name = @TblName
        AND Column_Name = @ColumnName
    ) 
        RETURN;

    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(1000) =

    N'SELECT @RetVal = CAST(IIF(EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@TblName) + N'
        WHERE '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' IS NOT NULL
    ), 1, 0) As Bit)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@RetVal bit output', @RetVal OUTPUT;

END
```

Key notes:

1. I've changed the `@TblName` and `@ColumnName` variables to data type `sysname` instead of your original `nvarchar(30)` - since that is the data type SQL Server use internally to store identifiers.
2. Since identifiers can't be parameterized, I've white-listed them.
3. I'm using `sp_executeSql` to get back the value of the dynamic query directly into my output parameter.

For more tips and tricks on dynamic SQL, you can read my blog post entitled [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/)

Comment: This works perfectly! Efficient code is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! If it's not too much to ask, could help me out with resources that can help me write code as efficiently as you do?

Comment: Every field have it's resources. When talking about SQL Server, there are communities such as [Sql Server Central](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/), [ms-sql-tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/) and others. Blogs by people like Itzik Ben Gan, Aaron Bertrand, Brent Ozar, Ronen Ariely and others are also a great read.

Comment: I'll check these out. Thanks again!