# How to get dynamic SQL query output into declared variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

In here I've declared two variables, one is for writing a query, the other is to store the output.

```
declare @EM_NUMBER nvarchar(100)
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL='select vendor.VD_TABLE_KEY_VALUE 
          from [HS_EM_VENDOR_DATA_MAP] as vendor 
          inner join [HS_HR_EMPLOYEE] as emp on vendor.VD_TABLE_KEY_VALUE = emp.EMP_NUMBER
          where vendor.VD_TABLE_NAME = ''HS_HR_EMPLOYEE''
            and vendor.VD_TENANT_UNIQUE_ID = ' + @VD_TENANT_UNIQUE_ID + '
            and emp.HIE_CODE_' + @DEF_LEVEL + ' = ' + @HIE_CODE + '
            and vendor.VD_TABLE_REF_VALUE = ' + @XeroEmpNumber
```

Once I execute this @SQL output something like this

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output:

[image]

I want to store this output into `@EM_NUMBER` variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get sp\_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

Comment: Careful, the above is a massive security vulnerability. You need to fix that huge injection issue you have by parametrising your parameters (seems silly to say, but you're not) and safely injecting dynamic object names with `QUOTENAME`.